# What does "put up" mean in "put up pets"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The opening narration of the movie *Meet the Blacks* goes"

> Hey, guys. Tonight is the Purge and I want all of my white friends to be safe. Rules of the Purge. You have 12 hours to do any crime you want against anyone you want. You can shoot, kill, stab. Twelve hours of death, mayhem. Lock your doors. Protect yourself. Make sure your rent is paid and **all of your pets are put up.**

I can't be sure if "put up" here means *to provide lodging* or *to preserve* (as in put up jam). Although it seems to mean "protect" or "pen up", I can't find definitions along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it means kept in a safe place. It is using the meaning *to provide lodging* in the sense that they will be kept indoors and out of the way of the people observing "The Purge". You are right in saying that they will be protected or penned up.